# Three buttons in UILocalNotification alert box

Tags: iphone, button, alert, uilocalnotification

In my iphone app i am implementing `UILocalNotification`. I want three buttons to be displayed in the alert box, which is displayed after the application closed through the `UIlocalNotification` invocation automatically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add one more button as in a `UIAlertView`. Since the notification alert is controlled by the OS, you can't customize it even though they are the same UI element.